# GLSL vertex shader on 3d model

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, vertex, vertex-shader

I am currently coding a simple vertex shader for a model. What I want to achieve is something like this :

I have a model of a dragon, nothing too fancy, and I want to shade the wings vertexes to move around a bit, to simulte flying. Now, this is for academic purposes so it doesn't have to be perfect in any way.

What I'm looking for precisely, is how do make for example only the vertices further from the center of the model move ? Is there any way I can compare the position of the vertex to the center of the model, and make it move more or less (using a time variable sent from the OpenGL app) depending on the distance to the center ?

If not, are there any other ways that would be appropriate and relatively simple to do?

Comment: Have you considered using an uniform to send current model's center to your shader? Then it is just a bit of vector math to do the rest

Comment: Yes, but since my model is in the 3d world, how do I pass that coordinate and work with it from there ? I'm a bit confused with all the camera/projection/view etc. and don't know how to compare world vertex position to world model position

Comment: You don't need to work in world space for this. As you pass your vertex positions in model space(right?), you can also use the same coordinate system for the center. (coordinate system)Transformations can be performed when all other math is done.

Comment: Is there any obligatory to do this with vertex shader? I would prefer to handle this in opengl side

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 vertex;

void main() {
    //get the distance from 0,0,0
    float distanceFromCenter = length(vertex);

    //create a simple squiggly wave function
    //you have to change the constant at the end depending
    //on the size of your model
    float distortionAmount = sin(distanceFromCenter / 10.0);

    //the last vector says on which axes to distor, and how much. this example would wiggle on the z-axis
    vec3 distortedPosition = vertex + distortionAmount * vec3(0, 0, 1);

    gl_Position = distortedPosition;  
}
```

It might not be perfect, but it should you get started.